# Is it possible to download a purchased 360 game to the pc, and then install it on the xbox via USB?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I currently have a very limited internet connection at home, and downloading a huge multi gigabyte file isn't feasable.

I do have access to very high speed internet somewhere else though, so is there a way to download a game I officially purchased via the Xbox 360 Marketplace to a PC and then use a USB to carry it home?

Note: I CAN use a bit of internet connection (tethering from my phone) if it needs some kind of verification that I've purchased it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not via PC no, but you could move your xbox to that location and download the file there?

Once the file is downloaded (and it's best to run it too if it's a game) then it'll be registered to your gamertag and that console. It'll then run without being connected to the internet in future (or connected with a slow connection). Obviously any patches for the game may cause issues again also, but you can repeat the above process.